# Vertical Alignment of Buttons with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I am pretty new to web development as a whole, and I have spent many hours looking up solutions for this on the web but I can't seem to find one that works when I try it.

Basically, I have a jumbotron that is reponsive vertically so the height is always 100%. I have a block of text that is vertically and horizontally aligned so that it is always in the center of the jumbotron.

My issue is trying to add a button that is also reponsive and is always vertically aligned at the bottom of the jumbotron. If I use the same code that I used for aligning the text, and change the offset percentage so that the button should be at the bottom, the button shows up in the right spot, but doesn't respond when I resize the browser unless I refresh!

Here is my code for the css part:

```
html, body{
       height: 100%
}

.jumbotron{
        height: 100%
}

.middle{
        position: relative;
        top:50%
        transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

And the html section goes:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1 class = "middle"> This text works fine </h1>
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary middle"> This button doesn't work
        </button>
</div>
```

The funny part is that the button places itself into the correct spot whenever I refresh the page, but if I am resizing the browser vertically, the text shifts to the correct vertical alignment but the button remains fixed.

Does anyone know how to fix this/a better way to deal with vertical alignment?

Comment: When i ran the above code, I found the expected behaviour..Look the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/naga2raja/chm1hv0b/embedded/result/ here and let me know what u need actually

Comment: @Naga2Raja The code seems to be working fine for me now as well. Earlier for some reason the button would not realign itself when I was adjusting the browser size but now it does... interesting

Answer (score 0):

The given code seems to have expected behaviour.

```
No change in code
```

Fiddle demo here : [Demo Code](https://jsfiddle.net/naga2raja/chm1hv0b/)

Try clearing browser cache and re-check again.